# docker runでCMDとして与えた引数のスペースが正しく処理されない

Tags: shellscript, sh, docker

以下の様なDockerfileとdocker-entrypoint.shを作成してビルドしました。

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:latest
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

#### docker-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo '$@ = '$@
echo '$# = '$#
OPT=`getopt -o "" -l "hoge:,huga:" -- "$@"`
echo '$OPT = '$OPT
```

やりたいこととしては、

```
docker run myimage --hoge="ho ge" --huga="hu ga"
```

のようにオプションを指定できるようにし、entrypoint.shで処理できるようにしたいのです。

理想では`getopt`でオプションが整形され`--hoge 'ho ge' --huga 'hu ga'`のような出力がされるはずなのですが、結果は

```
$@ = --hoge=ho ge --huga=hu ga
$# = 4
$OPT =  --hoge 'ho' --huga 'hu' -- 'ge' 'ga'
```

となり、`docker run`した時点でクォーテーション内の文字列がスペースで分断されている（？）ようなのです。
理想通りにentrypoint.sh内の`getopt`でスペース入りの文字列を適切に処理させるにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？　簡単のため`docker run`時のオプション指定方法は変えたくないです。

ちなみに、`docker run -it --entrypoint=sh`でコンテナ内から`/entrypoint.sh --hoge="ho ge" --huga="hu ga"`を実行すると

```
$@ = --hoge=ho ge --huga=hu ga
$# = 2
$OPT =  --hoge 'ho ge' --huga 'hu ga' --
```

となり理想通りに動いてくれます。

---

Windows 10 / Docker 1.10.0 (build 590d5108) / docker-machine 0.6.0 (build e27fb87)

Comment: docker-1.9.1/Fedora 23 では問題ないようです。
docker のバージョンはいくつでしょうか。

Comment: あっ済みません書き忘れました、Windows 10のDocker 1.10.0 (build 590d5108)とdocker-machine 0.6.0 (build e27fb87) です。
特にWindowsで使えるようにしたいのでホストは変えられません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows版Docker Toolboxのバグだったようです。（[参考](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/368)）
1.10.2へのアップデートで修正されました。